# Is it ever useful to use lubricating grease with EP additives anywhere on a bike?

Tags: lubricant

In the shops where I buy lubricating grease there are two main kinds:

1. Regular lubricating grease of semi transparent yellowish quality.
2. Lubricating grease with [EP additives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_pressure_additive) (Extreme Pressure additives) that is grey and not transparent.

**Is it every useful to use the (EP) lubricant of the latter kind anywhere on a bike?**

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is no, because loads, RPMs, and temperatures on bike bearings are all relatively low. Any of the common bearing greases are fine, and if the bike ever gets ridden in wet conditions then water resistance easily becomes the most important variable factor among greases.

Whether the drawbacks of any of the EP additives might ever come into play in any bicycle application I don't know. But using common moly EP lithium grease is fine.

Answer (score 2):

From the wikipedia page that you link to:

> Unlike antiwear additives, extreme pressure additives are rarely used in motor oils. The sulfur or chlorine compounds contained in them can react with water and combustion byproducts, forming acids that facilitate corrosion of the engine parts and bearings.[1]

So it sounds as though the EP additives shouldn't be used on a bicycle that will be out in the rain or otherwise exposed to water. If you do use grease with those additives, it would be best to find a grease that is designed for water exposure.

Answer (score 1):

If you get it cheap, then perhaps.

However I use a marine grease for everything that needs grease, on the basis its better for water exposure, and perhaps salt depending on your winter roads.